# View binding with include layout not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewbinding

I want to use view binding to bind the view in include layout. I had given the included layout with an id 'topBar' but still failed to access the views inside of it. And I try to use Android studio auto-fix to create a local variable to see its type. It shows type "android.widget . a"
I am using Android Studio4.0. Is this a bug in Android Studio?

My Activity

```
    private ActivityWalletBinding viewBinding;
    private ViewTitleBinding topBarBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewBinding = ActivityWalletBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(viewBinding.getRoot());
        viewBinding.topBar;
        android.widget . a = viewBinding.topBar; //Create local var using auto fix in android 
studio 
}
```

activity_wallet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        layout="@layout/view_title"/>
```

view_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/fl_tab">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:onClick="backClick"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon_back"
            android:tint="@color/gray1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_right_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:textColor="@color/enable_right_title"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            tools:text="假文字"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Is this a bug for android studio or something?

Comment: What is the version of your Android Gradle Plugin?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

Comment: Not that one. In your project-level `build.gradle`, what is the version of `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x`?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat It's 4.0.0. I copied the wrong line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do nothing on it and it just works automatically. I surely did clean, rebuild, restart Android studio... something at that time but not working. Maybe link another layout in another class would trigger something just fix it under the hood cause I set aside this problem and keep going.

2023/11/15 Update:
If you met any resource syncing problem in Android Studio, you can delete your whole folder and pull it from remote again. This would be  my last try for this kind of problem

Comment: same, i lost 1 hour, after just restart android studio and works

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was including a layout from another module and was not able to access the inner views in the included layout via binding and the problem was that I was not enabling the viewBinding in the module that contains the xml file that I wanted to include so adding

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

to the `gradle.build` of that module fixed it for me!

Answer (score -1):

xml level inclose your xml root with  tag

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        layout="@layout/view_title"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am asking for view binding rather than data binding